# Understanding the self keyword when referring to a class instance variable in a ruby?

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

I am trying to understand ruby objects and the self keyword.

Lets say I have a class:

```
class CashRegister
  attr_accessor :total

  def initialize(total)
    @total = total
  end

  def add(amount)
    self.total = self.total + amount
  end
end

cr = CashRegister.new(5)
puts cr.total #=> 5
cr.add(10)
puts cr.total #=> 15
```

Say I remove the self keyword in the add method above:

```
def add(amount)
   total = total + amount
end
```

I get an error:

```
cr = CashRegister.new(5)
puts cr.total #=> 5
cr.add(10) #=> this throws an error: ./lib/test.rb:28:in `add': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I am assumed this is because I need the self keyword to refer to the instance variable, total

Say I have another similar class:

```
class School
  attr_accessor :name, :roster

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @roster = {}
  end

  def add_student(student, grade)
    roster[grade] = roster[grade] || []
    roster[grade] << student
  end
end

school = School.new("Jefferson High")
puts school.roster #=> {}
school.add_student("Sam", 10)
puts school.roster #=> {10=>["Sam"]}
```

Why did I not need self in add_student?

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bruby%5D+when+is+self+needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: `foo = value` will always refer to a local variable `foo` not the method call `self.foo=(value)`.

---

> I am assumed this is because I need the self keyword to refer to the instance variable, total

No, `total` is a local variable, not an instance variable. `@total` is an instance variable. A local variable lives for the current scope, like a single method call. An instance variable sticks with the object.

You need the `self` keyword to refer to the method `total=`. Let's dive in.

`attr_accessor :total` declares two methods, `total` and `total=`. These are wrappers to get and set the instance variable `@total`. The following code does the equivalent.

```
def total
  @total
end

def total=(value)
  @total = value
end
```

Note that the method is named `total=`, this will become important in a moment.

With that in mind, let's look at your code.

```
def add(amount)
  self.total = self.total + amount
end
```

(Almost) everything in Ruby is really a method call. The above is syntax sugar for calling the `total=` method on `self`.

```
def add(amount)
  self.total=(self.total + amount)
end
```

Now what happens if we remove `self` like so?

```
def add(amount)
  total = total + amount
end
```

In Ruby, `self` is optional. Ruby will figure out if `total` means the method `total` or the local variable `total`. ***The local variable takes precedence*** and ***assignment is always to a local variable***.

`total = total + amount` works like so:

```
def add(amount)
  total = self.total + amount
end
```

Assignment is always to a local variable.

To further illustrate, what if we declared `total` first?

```
def add(amount)
  total = 23
  self.total = total + amount
end
```

The existing local variable `total` takes precedence over the `total()` method. `total + amount` refers to the local variable `total` and so `cr.add(10); puts cr.total` will be 33.

---

`total = ...`  will always refer to the local variable `total`. For this reason if you want to use method assignment you must explicitly use `self.total=`. In other cases you can drop the `self`. And avoid local variables with the same name as methods.

```
def add(amount)
  # self.total = self.total + amount
  self.total = total + amount
end
```

---

> Why did I not need self in add_student?

Because there is no ambiguity. You're not assigning to a local variable `roster`.

```
def add_student(student, grade)
  roster[grade] = roster[grade] || []
  roster[grade] << student
end
```

`roster[grade]` is really `self.roster.[]=(grade)`. You are calling `self.roster` which returns a `Hash` and then calling the [`[]=`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) method on that Hash to give it a new key/value pair.

Similarly, `roster[grade] << student` is `self.roster.[](grade).<<(student). Get a`Hash`, call [`[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) on it to retrieve the`Array`and call [`<<`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C) on that`Array`.

```
def add_student(student, grade)
  self.roster.[]=(grade) = self.roster.[](grade) || []
  self.roster.[](grade).<<(student)
end
```

Yes, `[]`, `[]=`, and `<<` are all methods names like any other.

---

A lot of Ruby mysteries go away once you understand the method calls under the syntax sugar and that things like `[]`, `[]=`, `<<` and so on are method names.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I made a couple repls of some examples so that I might be able to sort them out.

https://repl.it/@FergusDevelopme/cash-register-instance

https://repl.it/@FergusDevelopme/school-instance

Comment: @zippyferguson Good idea. They *both* write to the local variable because a defined local variable takes precedence over a method call. Once you have `roster = ...` in scope, subsequent references to `roster` will be to the variable, not the method.